How to get URL value in a NextJS 14 server component
I need to get a value from the URL to fetch data using Nextjs 14 server components.
For example

example.com/es/ (production)
localhost:3000?locale=es (local development)

I want to get the locale from each of these urls to query data from a headless CMS.
My original idea was to create a custom provider which got the locale from the url, save it to state to be accessed at a component level. I realised whilst having the data in state ready to use, I can't access it in a server component! I don't want to use a client component here to fetch data.
I've tried wrapping the server component in a client component to pass locale as a prop, but that didn't work due to using /app folder.
I've also tried setting a cookie and headers using middleware. This approach kind of worked, but was very temperamental.
What would be the best way to achieve this?

in a Next.js server component, you can get route parameters from params.
Example:
This is the route:
/app/[locale]/page.tsx

url would be
http://localhost:3000/es

Page example:
interface Params {
  locale: string
}

async function MyPage({ params }: { params: Params }) {
  const { locale } = params
  console.log(locale)

  return (
<h1>My page</h1>
  )
}


This has worked - thank you! I have noticed an issue though when trying to access sub pages. For example localhost:3000/us/example-page or localhost:3000/us/services/example-page. The [locale] folder see these parts of the URL as locales. Would you just nest more folders based on [uid] for example or would a different approach be needed?

Hi! I'm glad it works!
If you need to get more parameters from the URL, place the [locale] folder right under the app directory, and start adding more folders inside [locale].
URL
http://localhost:3000/es/profile/0101021324
Folder structure
/app/[locale]/profile/[userId]/page.tsx
Get the params in your page, server side
const {locale, userId} = params
